# Will my app work with a new iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have made an app for iOS 5.1..
Will the app work with iOS 6 also? Or do I have do to any updates in the code or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple has good backward and forward compatibility so it should work with no problem
There are cases when you use some specific libraries that your app will need a resubmission
but 99% of the cases your app will just work good

One point to note here: is if apple will change the resolution of their next devices you may find some icons that are low quality (happend when iphone 4 was first release)
But regardless of that your app should work.

Comment: Yes good point, and also he shouldn't worry for a while... iOS 6 will only go on public release probably a few months after announced (probably this WWDC)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the OS versions are backward compatible for the apps.

Comment: I didn't voted on your answer, but I assume this `There is no ios 6 as of now... so it may or it may not.. you will have to wait for ios 6.`is what gave you a -1. If you don't know if it will or not, don't say anything. `Usually the OS versions are backward compatible for the apps.` would be enough.